# Ionic Cordova disable third party keyboards on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard

I searched around but I didn't find any advice:
Can I disable third party keyboards in Android using Ionic and Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable a custom keyboard for your app since it's up to the user to decide which keyboard he/she would like to use.

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48500454/4614197) which basically states the same but for a native app.

Here's the main statement from the answer:

> You can't. The choice of the input method editor ("keyboard app") is up to the user, not you.